# Can a submitting-client directly invoke 'broadcast' from Orderers?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

According to the docs, a leading peer node communicates with orderer nodes on behalf of a member. This means, as I understood, two functions of orderers, which are `<broadcast>` and `<deliver>`, should be invoked by a leading peer. However, some parts of docs seems to say a submitting-client (a.k.a application with SDK) can invoke `<broadcast>` of Orderers directly and, at the same time, a submitting-client should have at least one peer to participate in the blockchain network.

So, does it means that a submitting client invoke `<broadcast>` function of Orderers through a leading peer? Or does a submitting-client can directly invoke `<broadcast>` function of orderers without passing through any peer node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submitting client do able to directly invoke the broadcast API of ordering service, one of the most obvious examples as the channel creation, where client has to submit configuration transaction (using broadcast) to the ordering service and get the genesis block (using deliver). Of course you need to make sure client has valid permissions to do it.